# og:image not being stored in opengraph, stream working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to use the open graph to mark up pages on a website as athletes, as follows:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Mo Rollem" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Bruisin Banditas" />
<meta property="og:description" content="-" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://bandita.circulartriangle.com/mo-rollem-3" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://bandita.circulartriangle.com/mo-rollem-3/download/portrait/297875_923184074920_36913142_46189728_1083603_n.jpg" />
<meta property="og:type" content="athlete" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="251338211564923" />
```

I have a standard like button installed at the top which functions correctly.  The story in my stream includes an image and pulls up the correct metadata.  The sportsperson section of my profile gains a new page with all the metadata except the image.

The Linter shows the image: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbandita.circulartriangle.com%2Fmo-rollem-3

But the Open Graph shows the question mark default: http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fbandita.circulartriangle.com%2Fmo-rollem-3

What am I doing wrong? Am I doing something wrong? There was a bug about this last year but it doesn't seem to affect any of the other sites I check.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue, I'm having the same problem where my og:image is not being found for facebook share.

Comment: It seems the scaper is running very slowly, and the image scaler even more slowly than that.  Plan for it taking 3 days.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The open graph system is very slow, sometimes taking many days to scrape, and even more to scale images.

Comment: Actually you can update the open graph at any moment using facebook's debug tool. Images are re sized immediately..

Comment: Not true, Adam. In the normal case that seems to be true, but it is asynchronous and in cases where the service is under very heavy load it can take days.  In this case, when I asked the service was partially unavailable.